# How to show the legends only in the box outside of the plots, using Subplots and Seaborn Lineplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I show non-duplicated legend, only in the legend box outside of the plots?

I have tried to add "lagend=False" in each plot but it didn't work.

Please help.

```
fig, axs  =plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(20,15))


sns.lineplot(data=data,x='Date', y='Daily Close Price',hue='Symbol', ax = axs[0,0])
sns.lineplot(data=data,x='Date', y='Daily Close Yield',hue='Symbol', ax = axs[0,1])
sns.lineplot(data=data,x='Date', y='Spread',hue='Symbol', ax = axs[1,0])
sns.lineplot(data=data,x='DGS10', y='Daily Close Price',hue='Symbol', ci=99, ax = axs[1,1])

fig.legend(loc=7)
plt.show()
```

[image: here is what I have done]

Comment: try this:`g1=sns.lineplot(...);g1.get_legend().remove()`Repeat graphs.

Comment: @r-beginners thank you so much, it removed the legend boxes inside the plots. However, in the legend box on the right is still showing duplicated items, would you please help me fix that as well?

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but the following will help. `plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.2), loc='upper left')`